# Can I add a Scene kit scene to a standard view controller hierarchy?

Tags: ios, uikit, scenekit

I have a UIImageView in a view controller hierarchy that has a transition effect added to it. This is an undocumented effect however (@"rippleEffect"). I would like to achieve the same effect legally.

I am a complete newbie regarding Scene kit. Is it possible for me to add a scene to my standard view hierarchy? The view hierarchy consists of standard UIKit and Core Animation elements. I would like to add a scene kit scene that consists of a UIImageView added as a 'subview'. Can UIKit and Scene kit elements be mixed in this way? The UIImageView contains transparency that must be preserved.

Comment: I'd like to know a little more about the ultimate goal here. It seems the idea is to have a partially transparent picture with an animated ripple effect on top of it when you change images? In that case, it would see you could achieve the same end by applying the image to a rectangle in a SK view and then using CA on it. Check out the sort of thing here: https://www.objc.io/issues/18-games/scenekit/

Comment: Well I don't plan to change images although I can see why you would think so from my original post (sorry my use of transition effect was misleading). What I would like to do is perform an animatable 3D type warping effect to a UIImageView. So I am really trying to figure out if two things are possible. (1) Can I load an image into an SK View and have that SK View added to my view controller hierarchy made from standard view elements? and (2) Apply a warping animation to it (not achievable through standard CA)?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Make an SK object that is a flat rectangle and add the image to it. Then you can use the technique from the web page I linked to give it a 3d effect. It's very powerful and even works in the GPU. You can then place the resulting SK view practically anywhere. It's pretty great.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for saving me a potential unnecessary amount of time in learning a framework only to find out it will not work the way I hoped. I shall now delve into the the details and figure out how to make it so. Cheers!

Comment: My pleasure... and I think you'll find any time spent learning SK is worthwhile. It took a project of mine from "well maybe I'll do it if I ever get a week free" to "I have an hour, lets see that I can do..."